# Matrix Transformation for image

Tags: image-processing, matrix, matrix-multiplication, matplotlib-basemap

I am working on an image processing project in python in which I am required to change the coordinate system [image]

I thought it is analogous to matrix transformation and tried but it is not working, I have taken the coordinates of the red dots
[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply subtract by 256 and divide by 512.  The connection is that you see values of 256 get mapped to 0.  Therefore, 0 gets mapped to -256, 256 gets mapped to 0 and 512 gets mapped to 256.  However, you further need the values to be in the range of `[-0.5, 0.5]`.  Dividing everything by 512 finishes this off.

Therefore the relationship is:

```
out = (in - 256) / 512 = (in / 512) - 0.5
```

Try some values from your example input above to convince yourself that this is the correct relationship.

If you want to form this as a matrix multiplication, this can be interpreted as an affine transform with scale and translation, but no rotation:

```
    [ 1/512 0   -0.5 ]
K = [   0 1/512 -0.5 ]
    [   0   0     1  ]
```

Take note that you will need to use homogeneous coordinates to achieve the desired result.

For example:

```
(x, y) = (384, 256)

[X]   [ 1/512 0   -0.5 ][384]
[Y] = [   0 1/512 -0.5 ][256]
[1]   [   0   0     1  ][ 1 ]

[X]   [384/512 - 0.5]   [ 0.25 ]
[Y] = [256/512 - 0.5] = [   0  ]
[1]   [      1      ]   [   1  ]
```

Simply remove the last coordinate to get the final answer of (0.25, 0).